create doughnut graph with rounded corner segments
In syncfustion library the doughnut graph, we have a cornerstyle property, setting its value to bothCurve gives a circular arch that's not desirable, we want to make only the corner rounded no arch. (see design).
I tried making the CustomDoughnutSeries series and extending the DoughnutSeries and DoughnutSeriesRenderer graph but couldn't accomplish it.
I need to know how I can approach this issue. any code sample help is appreciated.

